# Change PHP Shortcode depending on anchor tag in URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, anchor

Wanting to change a shortcode based off what the URL's anchor is displaying. So for example *(In pseudo code)*:

```
<?php
 if(url="/example-page#anchor1") {
   echo do_shortcode('[example_shortcode_1]')
 }

 if(url="/example-page#anchor2") {
   echo do_shortcode('[example_shortcode_2]')
 }

 if(url="/example-page#anchor3") {
   echo do_shortcode('[example_shortcode_3]')
 }
?>
```

Any idea on how I could possibly do this? I **CAN** do it in jQuery/JS if PHP is not possible.

Comment: #hash values are not part of the standard request data for the server so it won't be available in $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] for example. You'd need to use JS to do something with it. It also makes more sense to have it has JS anyways.

Comment: Hey Kyon, that's totally fine! I can do it via JS if needed. Do you have any JS possibilities?

Comment: building on what Kyon147 said, the `#` is typically a `client-side` thing anyway.  performing operations on it client-side makes sense.  You may consider making multiple pages if you are requesting them directly, but I suspect a JS solution would suit you best.

Comment: `window.location.hash` will get the hash including the #. Then you can just do your id statement and then what you want. To pull a different shortcode though from the server you'd need to use AJAX. Unless you just want to change it in the DOM the JS can do it.

Comment: Is there any examples you could provide? Sorry to be a pain!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I would probably parse the hash client-side `location.hash`, and then send that value server-side via jQuery, then run your short-code and dynamically populate the needed area. If you are doing anything more complex than that, then as @NappingRabit stated, you should probably make multiple pages.

Comment: For simplicity sake and not having to constantly ask if I'm doing it right, could you provide an example in your original post? No worries if you don't have the time!